# EmberJS: Chaining methods from Controller to Route

Tags: ember.js

first off, I'm a newbie to the world of EmberJS trying to explore and understand what's this framework is all about and I'm working with EmberJS version `1.0.0-rc2`.

## Problem Description

---

I have the following situation on a simple 'authentication' workflow where I want to pass values from one state to another on calling `transitionTo`, whereas the values should be taken from one view and passed into the other one also. to clarify my situation here a short description of the workflow (@Login and @Reset are representational for the corresponding route/controller/model/view components):

*Workflow:*

- @Login: User tries to login with his credentials (account, username, password)
- @Login: User failed to login because he forgot his password
- @Login: User decides to reset his password and clicks on the link to get to the 'reset password' screen with the corresponding
- @Reset: User has already filled out the values for 'username' and 'password' on the previous screen and therefore they are provided here
- User just has to click on the button to get a mail for the password reset link.

so, as I have understand it, I should handle all things which are changing the state (navigate from 'login' to 'reset') within the `Route`, things such as the login or reset action should be handled within the `Controller`.

now, I want to pass the values for 'account' and 'password' from the @Login Route to the @Reset Route. I'm not able to access the `View` from the `Route` nor from the `Controller`, but I'm able to access the `Controller` from the `Route`, so I thought about handling the `reset action` in the `Controller` to get the values for both fields and call a method on the `Route` which then will execute the `transitionTo` method. is this a correct way of achieving this behaviour?

I'll give a little code example, perhaps it will help to see things clearer:

## Code

---

LoginController:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
account: null,
username: null,
password: null,
submitLogin: function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'authentication/login',
    data: { 
      account: this.get(account), 
  username: this.get(username), 
  password: this.get(password)
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
      var dStat = data.status.toString().toLowerCase();

      if (dStat == 'ok') {
        window.location.assign(data.data.redirect);
      } else if (dStat == 'warning') {
        console.warn(dStat + data.message);
      } else if (dStat == 'error') {
        console.error(dStat + data.message);
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.error('Got an ERROR on Ajax Request!');
      console.error('Status (' + xhr.status + ') - Error: ' + thrownError);
    }
  });
},

requestReset: function() {
  this.get('target').send('reset', { account: this.get('account'), username:  this.get(username)}); // <-- this is NOT working
}
});
```

LoginRoute:

```
LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function () {
  this.render('authentication-login',
    {
      outlet: 'main'
    });
  },

  events: {
    reset: function (args) {
      this.transitionTo('authentication.reset', args); // <-- does it work?
    }
  }
});
```

## Question

---

am I on the right path by chaining the actions like `view --> controller --> route (transitionTo) --> otherRouter --> otherController --> otherView` ? what is the "Ember Way" of doing this?

## UPDATE 1:

---

if I try to declare the dependency between my two `Controller`s like @MikeGrassotti suggested

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('login', { outlet: 'main' });
  },

  events: {
    reset: function() {
      this.transitionTo('reset');
    }
  }
});

App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  account: null,
  username: null,
  password: null,

  login: function() {

  }
});


App.ResetRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('reset', { outlet: 'main' });
  }
});

App.ResetController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['login'],
  accountBinding: 'controllers.login.account',
  usernameBinding: 'controllers.login.username'
});
```

I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('account', (null)) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.ResetController:ember198>: its 'content' is undefined
```

if I just declare the `needs` property for the `ResetController` and call `controllers.login.account` from the corresponding template I get no error, but I also get no value (given I typed 'asdf' as value into the account field of the login form)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am I on the right path by chaining the actions like view --> controller --> route (transitionTo) --> otherRouter --> otherController --> otherView ?

Yes in terms of transitioning, but no in terms of trying to pass parameters. The only time you should be passing args in a `transitionTo` is when a context is needed as in `transitionTo('post', somePost)`

> I want to pass the values for 'account' and 'password' from the @Login Route to the @Reset Route. what is the "Ember Way" of doing this?

Instead of passing values from one route to another, use bindings to access properties of your controllers. For example:

```
App.ResetController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['login'],
  accountBinding: 'controllers.login.account',
  usernameBinding: 'controllers.login.username'
});
```

Now just use transitionTo('reset') with no args to switch to the reset route.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer @MikeGrassotti, but I'm seeing the following error when I try it like this: `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('account', (null)) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.ResetController:ember198>: its 'content' is undefined.`.

Comment: here's my code snippet for the `ResetController` (I hope it's somehow readable in a commnet): `App.ResetController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['login'],
  accountBinding: 'controllers.login.account',
  usernameBinding: 'controllers.login.username',

  requestResetMail: function () {
    alert('Requesting Mail for User ' + this.get('usernameBinding') + ' @ ' + this.get('accountBinding'));
  },

  cancel: function() {
    this.set('accountBinding', null);
    this.set('usernameBinding', null);
  }
});`

Comment: I posted an update to my initial question to have some better formatting for the code examples and a slightly better explanation of my problem ;)

Comment: ok, I did some further research and it seems like the binding is working (as to expect) like in your example, but the values of the variables which are representing my `input` fields in the `Controller` are only changed on the `login` action of the controller, otherwise they are left unchanged (if I type something into the `TextField`) and therefore return the value of their initialization...

Comment: I found the error when I examined what was going on on application startup and I saw, that I got actually 2 instances of the `LoginController` object when I used `renderTemplate` from my `LoginRoute` without explicitly declaring the template controller first. thanks a lot for your answer - I'll accept it and close this question as the `Binding` works like a charm now ;)